# How to interrupt python interpreter embedded in C++ application

Tags: python, c++, cpython, python-c-api, python-embedding

We have a C++ QT application, we embedded python in it. 
We provided two interfaces to the user
      1. Execute file
      2. Stop execution.
We execute a python file in a non GUI thread, using PyRun_FileExFlags.
We would like to interrupt python file execution (assume python file has an infinite loop, it never completes execution).
How to interrupt?

We tried following
1. In main thread set trace using PyEval_SetTrace
2. (if user click on Stop execution) In the trace call back function we set error "PyErr_SetString"

1:setting trace function

```
PyGILState_STATE state;
state = PyGILState_Ensure();                
PyEval_SetTrace(TraceHook, NULL);
PyGILState_Release(state);
```

2:trace function

```
int TraceHook(PyObject *obj, PyFrameObject *frame, int what, PyObject *arg)
{
if (b_isInterrupted)
{
PyGILState_STATE state;
state = PyGILState_Ensure();
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyboardInterrupt, "Python Interrupted.");
PyGILState_Release(state);
}
return 0;
}
```

Python execution is not interrupted.
I expect python execution to interrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyEval_SetTrace` affects the **current thread** only.

You want [`PyErr_SetInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html?highlight=pyerr_setinterrupt#c.PyErr_SetInterrupt).  It interrupts (what Python considers to be) the **main thread**, regardless of the calling thread (which need not bother with the GIL).

Comment: Thanks Davis, how to interrupt the thread (which is not main thread) which is executing PyRun_FileExFlags

Comment: @srinivasM: I don’t think Python knows more than what thread called `Py_Initialize`—can you arrange for it to be the same one?

Comment: Thanks @Davis: it worked for main thread. Can you suggest if there is a way to stop other threads?

Comment: @srinivasM: There is [PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?highlight=pythreadstate_setasyncexc#c.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc), but I don’t know how to get its `id` argument.